# JavaScript - Array values blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a unique challenge:
While on URL1(random wikipedia page), make an ajax request to URL2(100 most common words wikipedia page), create array from returned data to be used later.

I have to run this from the console while on "URL1"
example:

1. Navigate to URL1
2. Open Console
3. paste code
4. hit enter

So far I have been able to get very close with the following:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) { 
          Names = $.map($(data).find('.wikitable tr'), function() { 
return $(this).find('td:last').text()});
console.log(Names);
    }           
});
```

But I'm getting blank values in my array.

While on URL2(link in the ajax request) the following code works perfect

```
var Names = $('.wikitable tr').map(function() { 
return $(this).find('td:last').text() }).get(); console.log(Names);
```

I was gettin errors using this exact code because of the .get, after removing it, I got an array with the proper amount of elements, but they were all blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is right, you are just using the wrong functions. [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [`$().map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) are different function with different contexts and different arguments.

Your problem should be solved if you use the correct `map` function. Change

```
success: function(data) { 
    Names = $.map($(data).find('.wikitable tr'), function() { 
        return $(this).find('td:last').text();
    });
    console.log(Names);
}
```

to

```
success: function(data) { 
    Names = $(data).find('.wikitable tr').map(function() { 
        return $(this).find('td:last').text();
    });
    console.log(Names);
}
```

In the second form of `map`, the `this` keyword is set to DOM element.

I also noticed that would code is returning `105` texts instead of the `100` words in the table, as it is picking the table headers too. Another cool trick of `.map` is that if you return `null`, it will not include the value in the result. Therefore, you could something like

```
Names = $(data).find('.wikitable tr').map(function() { 
    return $(this).find('td:last').text() || null;
});
```

as a blank string evaluates to `false` so the `return` will return `null` instead of `''`. Or, you could just make your selector more specific, such as:

```
Names = $(data).find('.wikitable tr td:odd').map(function() { 
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Very thorough, I saw your first answer and checked it, came back to reply that it was correct and that I had a question about the blank header entries, only to find you had already edited and answered.  Talk about a mind reader!  Cheers and Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you also Inspect via F12, if any error is thrown.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: He's loading this from a different wikipedia page. Since it's the same domain, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That is correct Zequ, however, if I were to run it cross domain, how much of a change would that be?

Comment: @ZiNG from my knowledge, you probably won't be able to if you are just using this in the console. You can look into it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Js map to iterate over Jquery Objects(Html element Object)

```
$(data).find('.wikitable tr').map(function() { 
        return $(this).find('td:last').text();
```

JQuery map Works only on primitives Array not on object

```
$.map($(data).find('.wikitable tr'), function() { 
        return $(this).find('td:last').text();
    });
```